# How to find the fundamental matrix?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fundamental-solution

I'm stuck with this problem:

> Given $$\dot{y}=A(t)y, \qquad A(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1+\frac{\cos(t)}{2+\sin(t)}&0\\ 1&-1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Find $\phi^{t,0}$.

So I know I have to find the fundamental matrix because $\phi^{t,0}=\psi(t)[\psi(0)]^{-1}$, where $\psi(x)$ is the fundamental matrix. But I don't know how to find it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This system splits into two subsystems.
The first equation,
$$\dot y_1=\left(1+\frac{\cos t}{2+\sin t}\right)y_1$$
is separable:
$$
\frac{dy_1}{y_1}= \left(1+\frac{\cos t}{2+\sin t}\right)dt
$$
and has a solution
$$
y_1= C_1 e^{t}(\sin t +2).
$$
Substituting this to the second equation, one obtains
$$
\dot y_2= C_1 e^{t}(\sin t +2) - y_2
$$
or
$$
\dot y_2+y_2= C_1 e^{t}(\sin t +2).
$$
This is a linear first order ode, which has a solution
$$
y_2(t)=C_2 e^{-t}+C_1 e^{t}\left(1+\frac25 \sin t-\frac15\cos t\right)
$$
Thus, the fundamental matrix is
$$
\Psi(t)= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{t}(\sin t +2)& 0\\
e^{t}\left(1+\frac25 \sin t-\frac15\cos t\right) & e^{-t}
\end{array}\right).
$$